# Subversion Management Tools

Tags: linux, svn

we have a lot of users running in different shared and solo-owned repositories in Subversion. As part of our work, we do project-shared code and individual work, and we need to control access, ideally on a group basis. 
 Currenly, we use [SVNManager](http://svnmanager.sourceforge.net/) to allow users to manage access and create repositories. However, in order to get that working we had to do quite a bit of hacking.

Does anyone know of a free, open-source, linux-compatible SVN management system?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend SVN Access: http://www.jaj.com/projects/svnaccess/ or http://freshmeat.net/projects/svnaccess/
I have used it as is, and have modified it for an enterprise-wide solution at my day job.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative called [KDESVN](http://kdesvn.alwins-world.de/trac.fcgi) which you might want to try. However, I have never used it, so I cannot vouch for it.

Answer (score 1):

[svn-access-manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svn-access-mana/) seems to be a great open-source web administration GUI for SVN too (and currently active ...).

But I've finally adopted [USVN](http://www.usvn.info/) !

This question is very similar to [SVN admin management GUI tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672431/svn-admin-management-gui-tool/7257551#7257551) by the way ...

Answer (score 0):

I use KDESVN. Once it's set up it works great, but you only get one chance to set up your branch structure, so plan to create a test repository first.