# SVN admin management GUI tool

Tags: windows, svn, user-interface, admin

What GUI Administration / Management tools are there for an SVN repository on Windows?

Comment: What kind of administration did you want to do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Look at [visualsvn](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/):

> VisualSVN Server is a package that contains everything you need to install, configure and manage Subversion server for your team on Windows platform. It includes Subversion, Apache and a management console.
>
> User-friendly Management Console
>
> - Create, import and remove repositories
> - Create and delete folders in repository
> - Dashboard showing overview status of Subversion server
> - Manage Subversion security policy
> - Start, stop and restart service
> - Repository browser
> - Manage users and groups
> - Edit Subversion hooks

Comment: VisualSVN doesn't support svn:// protocol

Comment: Have used it for years and its great!

Answer (score 7):

I recommend you look at [Subversion Edge](https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/projects/svnedge/).

Subversion Edge is a distribution of the latest versions of Apache Subversion, httpd and ViewVC all tested and designed to work together.  It also includes an easy to use web console for configuring and managing the server.  It is very easy to install and get running and includes a built-in updater that lets you install updates remotely via your web browser.  So you are always up to date with the latest security fixes and do not have to worry about the components not working together.

Subversion Edge is free and open-source.

Comment: The server is Apache Subversion, so yes you can implement hook scripts to add logic to the pre or post commit process.  SVN Edge even provides a web UI for uploading or editing the hook files if needed.

Comment: I strongly recommend this svn edge docker container https://hub.docker.com/r/mamohr/subversion-edge/ (2 min up and running)

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to admin a remote repository (whether it be a linux or windows box), or a local repository?

Personally I haven't come across any decent utility, so I use an AutoIT script that uses PuTTY's plink.exe to interface with *svnadmin* on my linux server.

**EDIT**: fairly lame code, but it serves my purposes. Assumes that you have a "conf/shared" directory in your $svndir, which will be shared by the repositories created by this script. Scripted with [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com)

```
$plink_bin = "C:\path\to\plink.exe"
$svndir = "/subversion"
$sshuser = "username"
$hostname = "host.domain.com"

$proj = InputBox("Enter project name", "Please enter a subversion project name", "")

if ($proj = "") Then
    Exit(1)
EndIf

$arg =        "cd " & $svndir & ";"
$arg = $arg & "svnadmin create " & $proj & ";"
$arg = $arg & "rm -fr " & $proj & "/conf;"
$arg = $arg & "ln -s ../conf/shared " & $proj & "/conf"

$command = $plink_bin & " " & $sshuser & "@" & $hostname & " " & $arg
Run($command)
```

Comment: looking to admin a remote repository. A good GUI for local should also be fine

Comment: The tools I've seen either require setting up server-side web-managed stuff, or control svnadmin through telnet or ssh. Which level of control do you need? Creating repositories isn't too bad.

Comment: OK, then you'll probably want to go for one of the webserver-based solutions - don't have experience with that, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

[svn-access-manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svn-access-mana/) seems to be a great open-source web administration GUI for SVN too (and currently active ...).

Try also [USVN](http://www.usvn.info/).

Answer (score 1):

[uberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com/download) makes Subversion admin easy, and is available for Windows, Mac and various Linux flavours:

Free, easy to implement UI for Subversion which includes:

- Everything you need to setup a Subversion server, including the latest version of Subversion and Apache.
- Toggle feature lets you deploy with 1.7.5 or 1.6.18 and upgrade or downgrade anytime.
- A very quick and easy setup wizard.
- A social coding environment.
- Easy to use administration console.
- Advanced LDAP functionality.
- Support for offline installations.
- Support for those that need to access the internet via a different machine (proxy).

Comment: uberSVN is not available anymore

Answer (score 0):

There's also my own program called [PainlessSVN](http://www.datakido.com/downloads/Token/ViewInfo/ItemId/4). It only works with repositories setup to be served with svnserve.exe It can work with Subversion servers in your LAN. I'm currently working on version 1.1, which is almost a complete rewrite. Check the blog to see what the new stuff is.

If you want to work with an existing Subversion server, then my program will work for you. If you want to start from scratch, then [VisualSVN Server](http://visualsvn.com/server/) is pretty good.

Comment: the PainlessSVN is not exist now!

Comment: Website had a hiccup. It's back up.

Comment: @HectorSosaJr PainelsSVN website does not seem to work now.

Comment: Moved to a new website. The URL in the post has been modified to point to the new location. Development of PainlessSVN has been discontinued though.

Answer (score -1):

found this tool : http://sublimesvn.com/download/index.html

This is a beta release of Sublime. It is free to use without restriction until it expires on September 1st, 2009. Pricing will be announced when Sublime 1.0 is released later this year.