# Subversion server wrapper + Windows GUI like VisualSVN, which product am I talking about?

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn, svn-server

I came across a competitor product to [VisualSVN](http://-) a few days back. It provides an installer and graphical wrapper around a standard `svn` server, plus (that's why I'm looking for it) repository backup and monitoring functions.

I can't for the life of me remember the product's name. I just remember they had a nice-looking, very minimalistic, slightly web2.0-ish web site (but in a nice way).

It's a commercial product but with some sort of community edition.

Does anybody know what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be one of these (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672431/svn-admin-management-gui-tool)):

- http://www.sublimesvn.com/download/index.html
- http://painlesssvn.com/

Comment: It was sublime. But I will take a look at painless, too, just because of the name. Thanks!

Comment: @Pekka: you are welcome. We are beating McDonald's in Time to Customer Satisfaction :D