# SVN administration tools

Tags: svn, user-interface, repository, administration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SVN admin management GUI tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672431/svn-admin-management-gui-tool)

Can somebody recommend some good GUI tools for administration SVN repository?

I need just to add read, write user permissions.

I searched posts on stackoverflow and google and didn't find appropriate tool.

Tnx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/672431/876298

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to VisualSVN Server if you're on Windows:
http://www.visualsvn.com/server/