# Is there any GUI tool for SVN repository Administration for Linux server?

Tags: linux, svn, centos, visualsvn

I was trying to install SVN on a linux server. I have tried UberSVN (but my boss doesn't likes it). Then I have tried (default) Apache SVN. But it is difficult to admin as everything is done in command line. I searched in stack but found question for windows SVN [SVN admin management GUI tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672431/svn-admin-management-gui-tool)

I want a good SVN tool with nice GUI for admin purpose which would work in Linux.
Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE 1**

The svn should be compatible to all the following clients. 
Eclipse, Adobe Dreamweaver, Xcode (MAC), Tortoise svn

Comment: Why don't you like command line tools? They are adequate for svn administration, because you can combine them (with standard tools like `grep` or `awk` ...) effectively!

Answer (score -2):

This could be a option and looks like a good one:

http://www.svn-access-manager.org/downloads/